# Google sheets to IFTTT

Tags: google-sheets, ifttt

I have a spreadsheet that contains data in columns from A to N. I've created an IFTTT applet so that it triggers everytime a new row is posted and auto posts into a subreddit. The applet works fairly fine, but it only pulls data from Columns A to J, the rest from K to N is ignored.
I tried many times and also did create a new Google sheet to check if the sheet had an issue, but the same happens.
Could anyone please help me, I'm a noob at programming what am I missing ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommended to use [zapier](https://zapier.com/) for more control :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact limit today.  Only columns A - J are available as ingredients.  If I moved the contents of Col K to Col J, then it could be read.

Columns K+ are not offered as ingredients.

No error message was given.  Just trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is a limit of IFTTT. It limit only 10 columns to automate.  That's why it automates only up to Col J.

There are more other limits on https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260803229749-IFTTT-Service-Rate-Limits